# TroubleShooting JOptionPane error

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, joptionpane, flush

I have a question I have a program where I want to test the users ability to remember a random list of colors. Based off if the users input is right or wrong it will ask for the next color.

So I got it all work up to where the user inputs the first color. Before it has the user input on the first color. The program is already assuming the user input is wrong, even tho it hasn't asked for any input.

I know from previously knowledge I could like flush the buffer, can you do that with JOptionPane?

Or is this another issue I'm not seeing?

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Testing
{
   //Intialization of the whole program for everything to pass information
   public JFrame main;
   public JLabel lbInsturctions;
   public JLabel welcomeMessage;
   public JLabel homeScreen;
   public JLabel homeScreenColors;
   public JTextField txtInput;
   public int num = 1;
   public String colorList = "";
   public String[] color = {"red","green","blue","brown","yellow", "gold", "orange", "silver"};
   public String[] solution = new String[5];

   //sets up the window and random colors
   public Testing ()
   {
      Random r = new Random();

      for (int i = 0; i<solution.length; i++)
      {
         solution[i] = color[r.nextInt(7)];
         colorList = Arrays.toString(solution);
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Lets test your memory. Memorize these colors: " + colorList);

      main = new JFrame ();
      main.setSize (500,300);
      main.setTitle ("Ultimate Colors");
      main.setDefaultCloseOperation(main.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      main.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      intializeGame();
      main.setVisible(true); 
   }


   public void intializeGame () 
   {
      //All Intiazations
      lbInsturctions = new JLabel();
      homeScreen = new JLabel();
      txtInput= new JTextField(null, 15);  


       //Need to delete or make new window if user pushes ok then  
       lbInsturctions.setText("Enter color number " + num + ":");  
       main.add(lbInsturctions); 
       main.add(txtInput);

       txtInput.addActionListener(new colorTester());       
    }

    public class colorTester implements ActionListener
    {

      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
      {  


         //Need to delete or make new window if user pushes ok then  
         lbInsturctions.setText("Enter color number " + num + ":"); 

         //grabs the users input to see if it is corect
         String guess= "";
         guess = txtInput.getText();

         System.out.println(guess);

         //Checks to see if the users input is the same as the initalizaton
         if (color[num+1].equalsIgnoreCase(guess) || num > 6)
         {
            System.out.println("You got it!");  
            ++num;

            lbInsturctions.setText("Enter color number " + num + ":");
            txtInput.setText("");
         }

         //if the User input is wrong
         else
         {
            System.out.println("It's a good thing your not graded!");
            txtInput.setVisible(false);
            lbInsturctions.setText("It's a good thing this is not graded!");
          }

          if (num == 5)
          {
            lbInsturctions.setText("You memory is perfect good job!");
            txtInput.setVisible(false);
          }

        }




   }


}//end of program
```

Answer (score 1):

This has *nothing* to do with flushing buffers.

You're getting user input here: `guess = txtInput.getText();` which is in the `intializeGame` method. Meaning you're getting the text from the txtInput JTextField on its creation, **before the user has had a chance to enter anything into the field**. I think that you're used to programming linear console programs, where you get the user's input immediately, but that's not how event-driven GUI's work. Instead you must get and react to the user's input **on event**, here perhaps the ActionListener of some button. Perhaps your code needs a "submit" JButton or something similar, and in its ActionListener, extract the input from the JTextField and respond to it. Do this and your code has a better chance of working.

Other issues:

- you don't ever appear to have added your txtInput JTextField into the GUI.
- same for the homeScreen JLabel

---

Edit your *new* code posted at the bottom of your question has the same problem.

Comment: Well I have been trying to do this for awhile so I have tried so many different thing I have a few different things. So I added my other program that I tried what you said (cause I tried something similar already). But then how do I clear the: "Are you ready text" and button? Then add the txtinput thing

Comment: @noreturn: if you want to swap "displays", then use a CardLayout. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), but that is a completely different issue.

Comment: Also I tried using: homeScreen.setVisible(false);
btnOK.setVisible(false);

I dont want to swap displays, should all be in the same window. Just rotate thru.

Comment: Then call `revalidate()` and `repack()` on the *container* that holds these components (the main's contentPane) after making any changes, so that they show up in the GUI.

Comment: @noreturn: but again, those are other problems. Your main problem stems from getting the user's input too early, and again the solution is to not do this, to only get the user's input when they indicate that it should be submitted, either via JButton or JTextField ActionListener.

Comment: I'm pretty lost to be honest. Sorry I'm pretty new at this stuff. So is my first or second program probably the easier way to do it? Or cleaner? And where is the problem. If I am understanding right your saying I need to have another active listener for the txtInput?

Comment: Figured it out, your the best!